# JavaScript datatype function validity

Tags: javascript, function

Here is a simple example of a function and its datatype:

**Code Snippet:**

```
function hello(){
    console.log("hello");
}
console.log(typeof(hello)); //function
```

**Query:**

In JavaScript these are the datatypes:

```
1. Object
2. Primitives - String, number, boolean, null, undefined, symbol(ECMA6)
```

When there is no datatype named 'function' then how in the world am I getting the datatype as **function** (though logically its correct). Also, textually it is written that datatype of function is object. So, I must have got result as **object**.

Can someone clarify this confusion?

Comment: [__The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), Not really a `data type`

Comment: Because `"function"` is what the spec says to return? (Which makes sense, whereas `typeof null` returns `"object"`.)

Comment: Yes both of these cases are confusing. Also, is there any other way to test the datatype of a variable other than typeof -- as it returns spec or indicates type of unevaluated operand? (As per the above 2 comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right, there's no `function` type, it's just a hack in the `typeof` operator that returns `"function"` for objects that are callable.

Reference: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator

Generally speaking, `typeof` does return the actual type name, with two exceptions:

- `typeof null` returns `object`, but the type of `null` is `Null`
- `typeof <func>` returns `function`, but the type of `<func>` is `Object`

Comment: This means that the correct answer should have been object only, but in the current scenario due to some specifications -- "It is giving function", but in truth it should have been "Object"?

Comment: Also, add typeof(Nan) === "number" in the exception list!

Comment: But, I thought its real semantic meaning is "not a number"! Then how can its datatype be a "number"! Confused ...

Comment: @Peterson: yep, `NaN` is a "Number" which is not a number. Confusing indeed, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 2):

From the "You don't know JS book" by Kyle Simpson:

> So what’s the seventh string value that typeof can return?

```
typeof function a(){ /* .. */ } === "function"; // true
```

> It’s easy to think
>   that function would be a top-level built-in type in JS, especially
>   given this behavior of the typeof operator. However, if you read the
>   spec, you’ll see it’s actually somewhat of a “subtype” of object .
>   Specifically, a function is referred to as a “callable object”— an
>   object that has an internal [[Call]] property that allows it to be
>   invoked.

It was made to differentiate "callable" objects from "non-callable" ones.

Comment: Seeing this, I believe function should have been a datatype itself or at-least instead of returning function --- typeof return should have been "callable object" -- That would have made better sense!

Comment: Functions have some object behavior - it has prototype, properties (like "length" - the number of arguments, "name", etc) and methods (including object-specific "toString", "valueOf"), and that's might be the reason why they are a subtype of object instead of a separate type. The "function" word is likely used to avoid confusion for people coming from another languages.